# Universal Property of Localization

Tags: ring-theory, universal-property

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1\not =0$, and let $D\ni 1$ be a multiplicative subset of $R$. Consider the universal characterization of $D^{-1}R$:

There is a morphism $\pi\colon R\to D^{-1}R$ such that for all rings and morphisms $\psi\colon R\to S$ satisfying

- $\psi(1)=1$
- $\psi(D)\subset S^{\times}$

there is a unique morphism $\Psi\colon D^{-1}R\to S$ such that $\Psi\circ\pi=\psi$.

---

Suppose $D^{-1}R\not=0$. Prove directly from the universal characterization that $\pi(D)\subset (D^{-1}R)^{\times}$.

*Note: See p. 707 in Dummit and Foote*

Comment: Burn all those books which assume $1 \neq 0$ and $bla \neq 0$ where it is not necessary at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate further? In principle, assuming $1\not=0$ seems ugly. But how do you get around making such assumptions? Among rings with identity, the zero ring is an oddball and sometimes we need to make an exception for it.

Comment: The zero is not odd, it is a ring with 1, and it's totally unnatural to exclude it. And it is not true that we need an exception for this ring. Sorry I won't name the 100 reasons for this, because this has already been discussed here a lot of times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The universal "characterisation" you provided is just a property that is only a piece of the true universal property. You can think of it as saying $\phi:R\to D^{-1}R$ is initial; but with respect to what property? Just say that every map $R\to S$ that inverts $D$ factors through $R\to D^{-1}R$ is clearly not enough to characterise $D^{-1}R$.

Consider morphisms $\pi:R\to S$ such that: $\pi(d)$ is invertible for every $d\in D$, if $\pi(x) = 0$ for some $x$ then $dx = 0$ for some $d\in D$, and every element of $S$ is of the form $\pi(r)\pi(d)^{-1}$. Then there exists a ring $D^{-1}R$ together with a morphism $\pi:R\to D^{-1}R$ that is initial with these properties.

In other words, for every $f:R\to S$ with the above properties, there is a unique $g:D^{-1}R\to S$ such that $f = g\circ\pi$. In short, the universal property needs to be stated with the extra properties as above for $\pi$. Factoring every morphism uniquely which inverts $D$ is insufficient to characterise $D^{-1}R$, but I can see how page 707 of Dummit and Foote might have led you to this conclusion. You can find a lucid discussion with proofs in Atiyah and MacDonald's Commutative Algebra pp.37-38.

In this correct setting, your exercise is just part of the definition.

Comment: This answer is at best misguided, and at worst plain wrong. The map $R \to D^{-1}R$ _is_ an initial object in the coslice category of maps $\{ \pi : R \to S \mid \pi(D) \subseteq S^\times \}$, hence is characterized up to unique isomorphism. The additional conditions listed in this answer actually force $S$ to be isomorphic to $D^{-1}R$, i.e. there are _no_ other rings satisfying these stronger conditions. So while this technically is _a_ universal property, it is not the "true" one that is commonly used

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking at this exercise for some minutes now, and I'm deeply confused. Please correct me if I am wrong (and I am sorry for that), I'm only writing as an "answer" here because this might be too long for a comment.

I don't think you can solve this question purely by using the universal property given above.
Why is this?

There is a morphism $id: R \rightarrow R$ such that for all rings and morphisms $\psi: R \rightarrow S$ satisfying

- $\psi(1)=1$
- $\psi(D) \subset S^{\times}$

there is a unique morphism $\Psi: R \rightarrow S$ such that $\Psi \circ id = \psi$.

Hence from this point of view, we are in the same setting. However, the statement here is certainly not true.

(I know it's not a healthy reference, but the universal property given in the wikipedia article on the topic includes the property $\pi(D) \subset (D^{-1}R)^{\times}$)