# Localization of maximal ideal is again a maximal ideal and the residue fields are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Following is Lemma III.3.6 of Lorenzini's "An Invitation to Arithmetic Geometry":

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $m\subset A$ be a maximal ideal. If $D\subset A\backslash m$ is a multiplicative set, then the fields $A/m$ and $D^{-1}A/D^{-1}m$ are isomorphic.

After spending one week, trying to figure out what the author wants to say in the proof, I think following are the key steps needed:

1. Show that $D^{-1}m$ is a maximal ideal of $D^{-1}A$.
2. Using the following composition of ring homomorphisms (where $f$ is defined as $f(x) = x/1$ and need not be injective)
   $$A\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} D^{-1}A \stackrel{\pi}{\rightarrow} (D^{-1}A)/(D^{-1}m)$$
   and [the universal property of localization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/620756/214604), need to conclude the desired isomorphism.

I am now tired of trying to understand the proof and hence will be grateful if somebody could shed some light on how to prove this lemma.

In case you are interested, following is the proof given by Lorenzini (taken from [Google books](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=cVeZAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA350&ots=j6Vvn7p5kE&dq=Lorenzini's%20%E2%80%9CInvitation%20to%20Arithmetic%20Geometry%E2%80%9D%20lemma%203.6&pg=PA97#v=onepage&q&f=false)):
[image]

Comment: Just a small remark: I think the map $f$ is injective. Since $m$ is maximal, $A \setminus m$ contains no zero-divisors. The injectivity of $f$ follows from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the author proves (I use his own notations) that the map:
\begin{align}
h:A/P &\longrightarrow S^{-1}A/S^{-1}P\\
a\bmod P& \longmapsto \frac{a}1 \bmod S^{-1}P 
\end{align}
is surjective (which ensures it is bijective, hence an isomorphism since a homomorphism *from* a field is necessarily injective).

For this, he takes an element $\dfrac as\bmod S^{-1}P \in S^{-1}A/S^{-1}P$ and uses that $s$  is a unit mod. $P$ since $s\not\in P$ and $P$ is maximal, so that $\:\langle\, s, P\,\rangle=A$. This means there exists $t\in A$, $p\in P$ such that $ts+p=1$, which is equivalent to $ts-1=-p\in P$.

Then a small computation:
$$\frac as=\frac{ta}{ts}\equiv\frac{ta}1\mod S^{-1}P= h(ta\bmod P)$$
shows that $\dfrac as\bmod S^{-1}P$ is in the image of $h$.

Comment: I think there are typos in this answer. Please check. Also, how do you prove that $S^{-1} P$ is a maximal ideal?

Comment: @rationalbeing: I've found a $-$ sign missing, when explaining $st-1\in P$ and a bad copy-paste in the first equation. Are there other typos?

Comment: he takes the element $\frac{a}{s} \mod S^{-1} P \in S^{-1}A/S^{-1}P$ and uses .... and there exists $t\in A, p\in P$ such that....

Comment: @rationalbeing: Well, what's the problem?

Comment: those phrases have typos (like missing S and capital P)

Comment: @rationalbeing: Oh! yes. I'm a living proof that typing errors are better detected by others :o) I think I've forgotten nothing. Thanks!

Comment: why $s$ is a unit mod $P$? Please elaborate the reason you gave (how to conclude).

Comment: $s$ is a unit mod. $P$ because the relation $ts-1\in P$ means $ts\equiv 1\mod P$, which shows $s$ and $t$ are inverses of each other modulo $P$. Does this make things clearer?

Comment: is it true in general that if $R$ is a commutative ring with identity and $x\in R-m$ where $m$ is a maximal ideal, then $x-1\in m$?

Comment: I think we are using the fact that $s$ is a unit mod $P$ to conclude that such a $t$ exists. Your argument is other way round.

Comment: I understood you argument in answer above. If we attach any element not in maximal ideal to it we should get whole ring.

Comment: @rationalbeing: It's exactly that. So any element not in maximal ideal is a unit mod. this maximal ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Though this is not the proof given by Lorenzini, the lemma can be seen as a consequence of the fact that localization is exact.

Consider the exact sequence of $A$-modules:
$0 \to m \to A \to A/m \to 0$

Localization gives an exact sequence:
$0 \to D^{-1}m \to D^{-1}A \to D^{-1}(A/m) \to 0$

This shows that $D^{-1}(A/m) \cong (D^{-1}A)/(D^{-1}m)$ where the isomorphism (of $D^{-1}A$-modules) is given by $\frac{\overline{a}}{d} \mapsto \overline{\frac{a}{d}}$. One checks that this is also a ring homomorphism.

Since we assume that $D \subset A\setminus m$ and $A/m$ is a field, every element of $D$ is invertible in $A/m$. Thus $D^{-1}(A/m) \cong A/m$.

Comment: What is the ring structure of $D^{-1}(A/m)$? What is meant by elements of $D$ being invertible in $A/m$?

Comment: @rationalbeing By definition of the $A$-module structure on $A/m$, $D^{-1}(A/m)$ is the same as $\overline{D}^{-1}(A/m)$, where $\overline{D} \subset A/m$ is the image of $D$ under the natural map $A \to A/m$ (this is a multiplicatively closed subset). This has a ring structure as a localization of the ring $A/m$. I actually mean that the elements of $\overline{D}$ are invertible, i.e. the images under the map $A \to A/m$.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\overline{D}(A/m)$? What is the multiplicative identity of this ring?

Comment: @rationalbeing that was a typo, I meant $\overline{D}^{-1}(A/m)$. This is just a localization of a ring.